# lcov branch coverage with emplace/insert in std::map

Tags: c++, googletest, lcov

I'm checking my gtest branch coverage with lcov 2.0, but I encountered many branchs caused by STD, such as `emplace/insert/operator[]` in `std::map` down below.

- g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
- gtest 1.12.x
- lcov/genhtml: LCOV version 2.0-1

Here is my source code

```cpp
// src/main.hpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class mytestint
{
public:
    mytestint() = default;
    mytestint(uint16_t id, uint16_t pr) : _id(id), _pr(pr) {}

    uint16_t get_id() const
    {
        return _id;
    }

private:
    uint16_t _id;
    uint16_t _pr;
};

map<uint16_t, mytestint> _test_map;
map<uint16_t, uint16_t> _test_map_pod;

void test_emplace(uint16_t id, uint16_t pr)
{
    // map with class
    mytestint temp = {id, pr};
    auto t = _test_map.emplace(id, temp);
    auto k = _test_map.emplace(id, mytestint(id,pr));
    auto s = _test_map.insert({pr, temp});
    _test_map[id] = temp;
    auto h = _test_map[pr];
    // map with uint16_t
    _test_map_pod.emplace(id,pr);
    _test_map_pod.insert({pr,id});
    _test_map_pod[id] = pr;
}
```

Here is my gtest code

```cpp
#include "src/main.hpp"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(MapTest, TestMap) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_emplace(1,1));
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_emplace(2,2));
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_emplace(3,3));
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_emplace(2,4));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

lcov will display that all calls to these functions have an unprocessed branch.

```
      92                 :           4 : void test_emplace(uint16_t id, uint16_t pr)
      93                 :             : {
      94                 :             :     // map with class
      95                 :           4 :     mytestint temp = {id, pr};
      96         [ +  - ]:           4 :     auto t = _test_map.emplace(id, temp);
      97         [ +  - ]:           4 :     auto k = _test_map.emplace(id, mytestint(id,pr));
      98         [ +  - ]:           4 :     auto s = _test_map.insert({pr, temp});
      99         [ +  - ]:           4 :     _test_map[id] = temp;
     100         [ +  - ]:           4 :     auto h = _test_map[pr];
     101                 :             :     // map with uint16_t
     102         [ +  - ]:           4 :     _test_map_pod.emplace(id,pr);
     103         [ +  - ]:           4 :     _test_map_pod.insert({pr,id});
     104         [ +  - ]:           4 :     _test_map_pod[id] = pr;
     105                 :           4 : }
```

Here is my command to generate lcov report.

```bash
    g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fprofile-update=atomic && \
    ./test && \
    gcov -o . test.cpp && \
    lcov --capture \
         --rc branch_coverage=1 \
         --directory . \
         --output-file coverage_all.info \
         --ignore-errors mismatch && \
    lcov --remove coverage_all.info '*/usr/include/*' '*/usr/lib/*' '*/usr/lib64/*' \
                                    '*/usr/local/include/*' '*/usr/local/lib/*'     \
                                    '*/usr/local/lib64/*'   \
        --rc branch_coverage=1 \
        --output-file coverage.info \
        --ignore-errors unused \
        --ignore-errors mismatch && \
    genhtml coverage.info \
            --rc branch_coverage=1 \
            --output-directory coverage_report
```

I would like to know is there any solution to these uncovered branches?

Is there a relationship between the uncovered branches here and the exceptions inside the `emplace/insert/operator[]` function? How should I raise an exception in these function?

---

#### update with exception

I try to thorw an exception in mytestint constructor

```cpp
    // type of _pr already modify to int
    mytestint(uint16_t id, int pr) : _id(id), _pr(pr)
    {
        if (pr < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("pr < 0 ");
        }
    }
```

with new test code

```cpp
TEST(MapTest, TestMap) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_emplace(1,1));

    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(test_emplace(2,-4));
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(test_emplace(3,-50));
}

TEST(VetorTest, TestEmplace) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(test_vector_emplace(1,1));
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(test_vector_emplace(2,-4));
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(test_vector_emplace(3,-50));
}
```

lcov result in this.

```
     93                 :             : map<uint16_t, mytestint> _test_map;
      94                 :             : map<uint16_t, uint16_t> _test_map_pod;
      95                 :             : vector<mytestint> _test_vector;
      96                 :             : 
      97                 :             : 
      98                 :           3 : void test_emplace(uint16_t id, int pr)
      99                 :             : {
     100         [ +  - ]:           3 :     printf("%u | %d\n", id, pr);
     101                 :             :     // map with class
     102         [ +  - ]:           3 :     mytestint temp = {id, id};
     103         [ +  - ]:           3 :     auto t = _test_map.emplace(id, temp);
     104   [ +  +  +  - ]:           3 :     auto k = _test_map.emplace(id, mytestint(id, pr));
     105         [ +  - ]:           1 :     auto s = _test_map.insert({pr, temp});
     106         [ +  - ]:           1 :     _test_map[id] = temp;
     107         [ +  - ]:           1 :     auto h = _test_map[pr];
     108                 :             :     // map with uint16_t
     109         [ +  - ]:           1 :     _test_map_pod.emplace(id, pr);
     110         [ +  - ]:           1 :     _test_map_pod.insert({pr, id});
     111         [ +  - ]:           1 :     _test_map_pod[id] = pr;
     112                 :           1 : }
     113                 :             : 
     114                 :           3 : void test_vector_emplace(uint16_t id, int pr)
     115                 :             : {
     116         [ +  - ]:           3 :     mytestint temp = {id, id};
     117         [ +  - ]:           3 :     _test_vector.push_back(temp);
     118         [ +  + ]:           3 :     _test_vector.emplace_back(id, pr);
     119                 :           1 : }
```

Throw an exception in constructor could solve branch coverage in `vector.emplace_back`, but could not solve in `map.emplace`;

I know this is because I used `mytestint(id,pr)` to construct an anonymous object in `map.emplace`, rather than directly forwarding the parameters of emplace to construct mytestint objects. Therefore, the exception here is thrown during the construction of anonymous mytestint objects, not in the emplace function.

Try to add another constructor in mytestint

```cpp
    mytestint(int pr) : _id(0), _pr(pr)
    {
        if (pr < 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("pr < 0 ");
        }
    }
```

And these branchs with exception are covered!

```
   112         [ +  + ]:           3 :     auto kk = _test_map.emplace(id, pr); 
   129         [ +  + ]:           3 :     _test_vector.emplace_back(pr);
```

But I don't know how to throw exception in`insert/push_back/operator[]`; It seems like I can only ignore these uncovered branch in `insert/push_back/operator[]`.

Comment: `map::operator[]` will call default constructor of `mytestint` if key is not found. `map::insert` will call copy constructor if to pass a lvalue and move constructor if you pass a rvalue. So you can add exceptions in these constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the uncovered branches are throw paths. Run gcov with

```
gcov -b -c -o . test.cpp
```

You will see something like the following in `.gcov` file

```
        4:   12:    auto t = _test_map.emplace(id, temp);
call    0 returned 4
branch  1 taken 4 (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 0 (throw)
```

It's hard to raise an exception here manually. One possible solution is to throw an exception in the constructors of `mytestint`.

Comment: Thanks, I got this result in main.hpp.gcov file `branch  2 taken 0 (throw)` with emplace and operator[], `branch  3 taken 0 (throw)` with insert

Comment: I tried to add a throw in mytestint constructors, modify _pr from uint16_t to int, throw an exception when `_pr<0`.Test with negative num of pr will add another branch with `[++]` to line `auto k = _test_map.emplace(id, mytestint(id,pr));`